# How to transpose columns in PowerQuery without duplicating columns names

Tags: excel, powerquery, transpose

After I import big number of JSON files to Power Query, the last step I have to do is to transpose the the table (to make the rows are the columns).

Unfortunately, when I did the transpose, I found duplicate columns! (see attachments to have an idea about the situation)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgroR.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxAKL.jpg)

I need a solution to transpose the rows or columns without having redundant columns as shown in the screenshots, and to have all values under the corresponding columns.

Comment: Do any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You should be transposing each individual JSON. Then when you append the JSONs together you wont have that issue

Comment: Your solution does work, but what if I have big number of JSONs (in my situation I have around140 JSON files)

Comment: Not sure why that matters

Comment: I have around 140 imported JSON files, in order to do certain analysis on the data that it contain. so it is difficult to do the analysis for each file one by one. 

Also, I think it is not practical to apply your solution on that big number of files.

Comment: You don't have to do the analysis one by one just the transpose and combine. If the number of files matters then you seem to be combining them manually which is the wrong approach

Comment: You mean that to do the following: 1. Transpose each json file. 2. Combine all files after the traspose process. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.